# Регулярное выражение количество просмотров

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста написать регулярное выражение на Python 3.6.Есть строки типа:

```
4 дні тому849 478 переглядів
33 730 переглядів35 хвилин тому
16 037 172 перегляди2 дні тому
14 947 360 переглядів1 тиждень тому
1 тиждень тому1 515 110 переглядів
```

(Порядок может быть именно такой, а вот количество просмотров может меняться)

Я пытался использовать нахождение просмотров по регулярному выражению которое находит числа(и то не все), но так оно собирает только первые числа.

```
import re 

match = re.search('[0-9]+','16 037 172 перегляди2 дні тому')
```

Как можно эту регулярку дополнить,что бы она собирала количество просмотров?

Пример выхода во втором примере: 33730

Comment: а что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: вот как вариант: `[re.search(r'([\d\s]*)\s*?перегляд(и|ів)', x).group(1).strip() for x in lst]`

Comment: Как вариант: `re.search('[\d ]+(?=\sперегляд)', string)`

Comment: Дописал, извините за задержку.

Comment: Если можете, оформите,пожалуйста,в виде ответа))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данной ситуации, как и вцелом, ответ зависит от того, как именно вам нужно вывести информацию.

Учитывая моё понимание написанного выше, привожу свой вариант решения самой задачи. Соответственно, дополняю как вы просили ваше **регулярное выражение**:

```
import re

info = ['4 дні тому849 478 переглядів', 
        '33 730 переглядів35 хвилин тому', 
        '16 037 172 перегляди2 дні тому', 
        '14 947 360 переглядів1 тиждень тому', 
        '1 тиждень тому1 515 110 переглядів']

for string in info:
    match = re.search('([0-9]+\s){2,3}', string)

    print(match)

    if match:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

Регулярное выражение: `([0-9]+\s){2,3}`
тут

- исполнительная часть выражения взята в скобки - сгрупирована
- `[0-9]` - совпадение с этим диапазоном *(можно заменить на более regexp'сное* `\d`*)*
- `+`- любое количество символов (в нашем случае от одного до трех, т.к. 3 цифры и пробел)
- `\s` - любой знак препинания (можно заменить на `[ ]`)
- `{2,3}` - количество повторений

> **Стоит учесть**:
>
> 1. Устойчивая конструкция сработает на любое цисло в последовательности *(например `2151 5188845 112`)* только с учетом пробела вконце последовательности
> 2. Будет выдавать ответ на значения выше тысячи *(в примере через  оформлены тысячи)*
> 3. Может быть любой знак препинания *(`\n` `.` `,` `?` и т.д.)*

Командная строка выдает мне следующее:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(10, 18), match='849 478 '>
True
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='33 730 '>
True
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='16 037 172 '>
True
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 11), match='14 947 360 '>
True
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(14, 24), match='1 515 110 '>
True

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.243 s
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ.А что в данном случае делают скобки?

Comment: Круглые - обычное объединение, групировка: ```(1+1)*2``` Фигурные - количество повторений отделено от выражение и сформулировано как: ```{2``` и (,) ```3}```

Comment: Ниже также есть хороший вариант , только с учётом слова (что очень хорошо в данном случае), а также приведением цифр в формат integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
((\d+\s*?)+)\s*перегляд
```

https://ideone.com/MHFngZ

```
import re

info = ['4 дні тому849 478 переглядів', 
        '33 730 переглядів35 хвилин тому', 
        '16 037 172 перегляди2 дні тому', 
        '14 947 360 переглядів1 тиждень тому', 
        '1 тиждень тому1 515 110 переглядів']

for s in info:
  match = re.search('((\d+\s*?)+)\s*перегляд', s, re.IGNORECASE)
  if match:
    n = int(re.sub('\s', '', match.group(1)))
    print(n)
```

```
849478
33730
16037172
14947360
1515110
```